# Adding a timer to my game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, timer

I am currently working on a html5 canvas game. I want to add a timer, so that you have a certain amount of time to collect as many items as possible in. I have tried a few ways of doing it, but due to my lack of skill and experience when it comes to javascript I have not yet made it work. So my question is how to do this in an as simple as possible way?

My code:

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please don't dot-out your question. If you want to delete your question, please use the delete link under your question so the question is removed from the Stackoverflow questions list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` is a very efficient way of doing timers in the browser.

**Some Benefits of requestAnimationFrame:**

- automatically synchronizes canvas drawings with the current display refresh cycle,
- multiple requestAnimationFrame calls are coordinated,
- automatically suspends the loop if the user changes do a different browser tab
- each loop automatically receives a highly precise timestamp. Use this timestamp to determine when to trigger animation work (like your end-of-game) and/or to determine how much animation work to do.

Here's how to make it work:

**Create 1+ javascript objects. Each object is one timer.**

Each timer object defines some work that should be done after a specified delay.

```
var timers=[];

timers.push({

    // this timer fires every 500ms
    delay:500,            

    // fire this timer when requestAnimationFrame's timestamp
    // reaches nextFireTime
    nextFireTime:0,        

    // What does this timer do?
    // It execute the 'doTimers' function when this timer fires
    doFunction:doTimers,  

    // just for testing: accumulate how many times this timer has fired
    counter:0

});
```

**Create an animation loop with requestAnimationFrame**

```
// the animation loop
// The loop automatically receives the currentTime
function timerLoop(currentTime){

    // schedule another frame 
    // this is required to make the loop continue
    // (without another requestAnimationFrame the loop stops)
    requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);

    // iterate through each timer object
    for(var i=0;i<timers.length;i++){

        // if the currentTime > this timer's nextFireTime...
        // then do the work specified by this timer
        if(currentTime>timers[i].nextFireTime){           

            var t=timers[i];

            // increment nextFireTime
            t.nextFireTime=currentTime+t.delay;

            // do the work specified in this timer
            // This timer will call 'doFunction' & send arguments: t,i
            t.doFunction(t,i);
        }
    }        
}
```

**Start the animation loop**

```
requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);
```

### Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var timers=[];
timers.push({delay:50,nextFireTime:0,doFunction:doTimers,counter:0});
timers.push({delay:500,nextFireTime:0,doFunction:doTimers,counter:0});
timers.push({delay:5000,nextFireTime:0,doFunction:doTimers,counter:0});

requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);

function timerLoop(currentTime){
  requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);

  for(var i=0;i<timers.length;i++){
    if(currentTime>timers[i].nextFireTime){
      var t=timers[i];
      t.nextFireTime=currentTime+t.delay;
      t.doFunction(t,i);
    }
  }

}

function doTimers(t,i){ 
  ctx.clearRect(0,100+i*20-20,cw,20);
  ctx.fillText('Timer#'+i+' with '+t.delay+'ms delay has fired '+(++t.counter)+' times.',20,100+20*i);    
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

When the game begins set a timer using the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function.

Since your game is currently running indefinitely I'd change the last bit of your code to give it an ending.

```
var time = Date.now();
var running = setInterval(run, 10); // Save this so we can clear/cancel it later

setTimeout(function() {        // Set a timer
  clearInterval(running);      // Stop the running loop
  alert('Game over!');         // Let the user know, do other stuff here
}, 30000);                     // time in miliseconds before the game ends
```